# Scaffolding Submit button doesn't call its post method when unobtrusive jquery validation is used

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, submit

I am using unobtrusive jquery for validations in scaffolding edit page. But, the submit button does not work when the jquery is present. If I comment the unobtrusive jquery file, and when I click on "Submit", the post event works properly without validations. Why the submit button does not work when unobtrusive jquery file is taken as reference in the .cshtml file. Please help me.

Comment: A sample of your code would be very helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler tool is your friend. I suspect you have a client side validation error, therefore no post happens.

From my tutorial

[enter link description here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)the required attribute is not enforced until you hit the Submit button, or enter text into the input field and remove it. For a field which is intitally empty (such as the fields on the Create view) and which has only the required attribute and no other validation attributes, you can do the following to trigger validation:
 1.Tab into the field.
2.Enter some text.
3.Tab out.
4.Tab back into the field.
5.Remove the text.
6.Tab out.

The above sequence will trigger the required validation without hitting the submit button. Simply hitting the submit button without entering any of the fields will trigger client side validation..

Comment: To add to this answer: Note that any model property that is, say, an int will be required unless it is nullable even if you don't put [Required]. If you have a radio button, say, and haven't added the "validation message" label then it can be hard to visually see that validation is triggered.